# WP7: How do I get valid GPS values?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to make my own cycle app.

When I start the app, I press a button ... now I want to measure how far (distance) I've cycled. When I'm done, I want to draw my route on a map.

How do I do this? Any sample of this somewhere? .. and I guess I need to wait for a perfect GPS signal before measuring distance ... how do I do this?

Thanks!!!
Mojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has a documentation explaining the use of Location on the phone at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431803(v=vs.92).aspx

There is also a sample app for capturing location information at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229128

To get an approximate measure of the distance travelled, you could use calls to [`GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to measue the distance between each point captured. *The accuracy of this would be dependent on the number of points gathered on the journey.*